# I am unable to upload media files larger than 8MB in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, azure

I am hosting this site through Microsoft Azure.

I just tried to append `define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '3000M');` into the `wp-config.php` file and that did not work.

I have tried to add a `php.ini` file into the root directory with no success. I also attempted to move that file into the `wp-admin` directory and then attempted the same thing in both directories with the file name `php5.ini` and nothing will work.

I tried adding the following code to the theme `functions.php` file (with no success):

```
@ini_set( 'upload_max_size' , '64M' );
@ini_set( 'post_max_size', '64M');
@ini_set( 'max_execution_time', '300' );
```

The ONLY other solution I have seen that I haven't been able to try is editing the `.htaccess` file. Where is that thing?! I've looked all through the source and just cannot find it. Also, what is the file NAME? Every post I've found has referred to it as "the .htaccess file" but I see nothing with that file type and cannot create one since I do not know what the actual NAME of the file should be.

Any help or other solutions would be much appreciated.

Comment: "Loaded Configuration File" from phpinfo() will tell you what ini file you are actually using, I would start there. max_post_size usually defaults to 8m. Do you control this server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default on Azure, the `upload_max_filesize` is set to 8M, we can change the built-in PHP configurations to enlarge it.

Here are the steps:

1, Add a .user.ini file to your root directory.

2, Add configuration settings to the .user.ini file using the same syntax you would use in a php.ini file. With your demand, your .user.ini file would contain this text:

```
upload_max_filesize = 20M
; Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept.
post_max_size = 20M
max_execution_time = 300
```

3, Deploy your web app.

4, Restart the web app.

You can read [official guide](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-php-configure/#how-to-change-the-built-in-php-configurations) for more information.

By the way, we can use FTP tool to connect your Azure Web sites server to create and modify the custom configuration file instead of redeploying the project.

The default root directory is *`D:\home\site\wwwroot`*.

Comment: This worked perfectly! I also used the first 3 steps from the resource that mredison provided to create the .user.ini file: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2015/10/09/logging-php-errors-in-wordpress-2/

Comment: How do I do the same job for WordPress hosted on Azure Linux VM, but not through Web Apps. I tried saving `.user.ini` file in the root WordPress directory. And restarted the VM, it still does not work.

Comment: @LuzanBaralL, as your question is little relative with original post, you could please ask a new question about your issue on SO.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a `php.ini` file and your `.htaccess` is in your wordpress folder. if you haven't enabled premalink under wordpress admin panel it doesn't create the file. after you have the `.htaccess` file you'll need to make sure to set `AllowOverride` to `All` instead of `None` in your web server configuration and enable `mod_rewrite` so it reads the `.htaccess` file. What Linux distribution are you running on your server? is this a windows server? what is the last `error_log` for uploading images on your web server? it gives you better idea of what's throwing the error. Is this `IIS` or `Apache`?

Answer (score 0):

- You need to create a .user.ini file, follow steps from 1 to 3 from this
  reference:
  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2015/10/09/logging-php-errors-in-wordpress-2/

  ```
  upload_max_filesize = 64M
  post_max_size = 64M
  ```
- Save your .user.ini file.
- Need to go to your web.config file and add this configuration to allow the same value in IIS.

```xml
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
  <security>
     <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="<valueInBytes>"/>
     </requestFiltering>
  </security>
 </system.webServer>
 </configuration>
```

For more information, please check this reference: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2016/06/15/uploading-large-files-to-azure-web-apps/